# VBA - Call function inside a sub (module)

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following function in `VBA`:

```
Public Function lorh(custo As Integer)
If custo > 10.99 And custo <> 0 Then
    lorh = "1.4"
Else
    If custo < 11 And custo <> 0 Then
        lorh = "1.35"
    Else
        If custo <= 0 Or custo < 0 Then
            lorh = "Valor Inválido"
        End If
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Now what I need is to call this function starting from a sub or better from a macro, so I can associate it to a custom button on the `excel` toolbar . Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you have that function inside of a module, you can directly reference it inside a worksheet cell, pretty much as you do with Excel's formulas.

```
=lorh(A1)
```

In order for your code to run from a macro button, it needs to be a **Sub** instead of a **Function**

I think the code below would work the way you want it, I removed redundant pieces as well as Barranka did.

```
Public Sub lorh()
    Dim lorh As String
    custo = ActiveCell.Value

    If custo > 10.99 Then
        lorh = "1.4"
    Else
        If custo > 0 Then
            lorh = "1.35"
        Else
            lorh = "Valor Inválido"
        End If
    End If

    ActiveCell.Value = lorh
End Sub
```

This macro would use the active cell value the same way you were using the *custo* parameter in your function.

Comment: okay you're right, however, and what I want to do something like the "AutoSum" that when you click the button it performs the function sum

Comment: If you want a button or macro to work like the _autosum_ feature, you would need to reference the active cell and then act upon it on your function, which should be a sub instead... Take a look at my edited answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use your function in your excel sheet, you only need to write it at any cell, just as andrux said.

If you need to call it from a sub, again, you only need to write it:

```
public sub aSubprocedure()
    ' Any variables and other instructions go here
    var = lorh(input)
    ' Your code goes on
end sub
```

Then you can assign your subprocedure to your button.

---

A few suggestions for your code:

I suggest the following 'clean up' for your function:

```
Public Function lorh(custo As Integer)
    If custo > 10.99 And custo <> 0 Then
        lorh = "1.4"
    Else If custo < 11 And custo <> 0 Then
        lorh = "1.35"
    Else If custo <= 0 Then
        lorh = "Valor Inválido"
    End If
End Function
```

Notice that `if custo <= 0 or custo < 0` is redundant... you only need `custo<=0`.

Hope this helps you